# Searching an sqlite3 database using bash

Tags: bash, sqlite

I'm creating a script to search an SQLite3 database as part of a larger project.

The script will search a text file called keyword.txt which contains a list of keywords (one on each line)
The array "my_array" contains a list of all fields in the database in the format "table.field".
Upon execution I get a return of the matched text to std out.
However, I would also like it to output the field or table that the keyword(s) exists.

**ie:  Keyword: pineapple found in table fruit.**

***or:*      Keyword: pineapple found in field fruit.name**

```
for FIELD in "${my_array[@]}"
do
        TABLE=$(echo $FIELD | awk -F'.' '{print$1}')
        sqlite3 database.db 'Select '${FIELD}' from '$TABLE'' | egrep -i -o -n --color -f keyword.txt

done

printf "\nSCANNING COMPLETE\n"
```

Comment: Btw,: Switch from `${my_array[@]}` to `"${my_array[@]}"`.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you can only find maximum of 1 unique fruit on any given TABLE FIELD combination.

If that is not the case, please let me know and I will modify the answer

```
for FIELD in "${my_array[@]}"
do
        TABLE=$(echo $FIELD | awk -F'.' '{print$1}')
        sqlite3 database.db 'Select '${FIELD}' from '$TABLE'' | egrep -i -o -n --color -f keyword.txt
        FOUND=`sqlite3 database.db 'Select '${FIELD}' from '$TABLE'' | egrep -i -o -n --color -f keyword.txt"`
        if [ -z "$FOUND" ]
        then
          echo "nothing found" >> /dev/null
        else
          echo "$FOUND found in field $TABLE.$FIELD"
fi
done
printf "\nSCANNING COMPLETE\n"
```

Comment: A ha!
I tried something similar but the difference is in the if statement!!
I was trying an if grep -z
This goes a long way towards what I am looking for.

Comment: A ha!
I tried something similar but the difference is in the if statement!!
I was trying an ' if grep -z ' 
This goes a long way towards what I am looking for.
At the moment the result I get from a file with the keywords apple and banana is:
 
**apple:
banana: found in field fruit.name**

I am looking for :

apple: found in field fruit.name
banana: found in field fruit.name

As a side note there's a typo on the FOUND line.